# What's "Hemma" in "Unis Minor Hemma Unis Major Nostrum"? (might be dog-latin)

Tags: motto, contemporary-latin

[image: Canal boat inscribed "Unis Minor Hemma Unis Magis Nostrum]

We saw this on a canal boat (not our image - the one we saw said "major" not "magis") and I could not figure out what the motto meant - mainly because I do not know who or what Hemma is.

The closest I've come to finding out is the suggestion it might be "Emma" latinized, as happened to [some medieval queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemma) but I am not sure what that would mean. "Emma - lesser than some of us and more than others"?

The plural "unis" is also confusing even if interpreted as a misspelling of "unius".

Like I said in the title, it could just be dog Latin - and the only way to know would be to find the boat and ask the owner!

All help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this is supposed to mean "one less of them, one more of us"? Although it clearly doesn't...

Comment: By the way, if you are wondering why you got a downvote, it's because I apparently have thick fingers and "my vote is now locked."

Comment: Where is this picture from? Knowing what the local language is might help.

Comment: It's a canalboat on the Lancaster canal in England - so English.

Comment: The quote in the title and the text are different.  The title has *major,* but the quote has *magis*.  To me, this does some like made-up for many reasons.  My best guess at the intended sense of it would be: "Hemma, younger than some and older than some of us."